# Prove: $ 1\times3 +2\times4 + \cdots + n(n+2) = \frac{1}{6} \times n(n+1)(2n+7)$ using Induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm told to prove this by Mathematical Induction:
$ 1\times3 +2\times4 + \cdots + n(n+2) = \frac{1}{6} \times n(n+1)(2n+7)$

This is what I have so far:

BC:
Try $n=1$:

$ 1\times3 +2\times4 + \cdots + n(n+2) = \dfrac{1}{6} \times n(n+1)(2n+7)$

$ 3= \dfrac{1}{6} \times 2(9) = 3$

So Base case is true:

IH:
 Let $n = k$.
$ 1\times3 +2\times4 + \cdots + k(k+2) = \frac{1}{6} \times k(k+1)(2k+7)$

IS: show that

$n \implies n+1$

I'm told to only work from one side, so I've attempted the left side (I was told I can't plug this into both sides).

We Have:

$ 1\times3 +2\times4 + \cdots + (k+1)(k+3) = ...$

I'm not sure where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `\cdots` and `\implies` ($\cdots$ and $\implies$) might be useful for further questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
1 \times 3+2 \times 4+ \cdots +k(k+2)+(k+1)(k+3)
  &=\frac{1}{6} \times k(k+1)(2k+7)+(k+1)(k+3)
\\[5pt]&=(k+1)\left(\frac{2k^2+7k}{6}+k+3\right)
\\[5pt]&=(k+1)\left(\frac{2k^2+7k+6k+18}{6}\right)
\\[5pt]&=(k+1)\left(\frac{2k^2+13k+18}{6}\right)
\\[5pt]&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2(k+1)+7)}{6}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: And then I plug in the original value for the answer, or can I just leave it be?

Comment: @EDEDE see edition.

Comment: Cheers, thanks!